# Live calculation - Shopping Cart in Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, shopping-cart

I`ve been trying to make an online form for customers to select the dish they want and for how many people it supposed to be. But I am having some trouble making it work with Javascript only.

What I had in mind was doing something like that:

- if the dish is checked
- then get the value of the dropdown menu
- calculate the total per dish
- do that for every single dish
- then in the `calculateTotal()` function I would sum all of the subtotals

```js
function priceDish1() {
  var quantity = 0;
  var totalPriceDish1 = 0;
  var dishPrice = 19;
  var quantity = document.getElementById("quantityDish1").value;
  var theDish1 = document.getElementById("dish1");

  if (theDish1.checked == true) {
    totalPriceDish1 = quantity * dishPrice;
  }

  return totalPriceDish1;
}

function priceDish2() {
  var quantity = 0;
  var totalPriceDish1 = 0;
  var dishPrice = 19;
  var quantity = document.getElementById("quantityDish1").value;
  var theDish1 = document.getElementById("dish1");

  if (theDish1.checked == true) {
    totalPriceDish1 = quantity * dishPrice;
  }
  return totalPriceDish1;
}

function calculateTotal() {
  var theTotalPrice = totalPriceDish1() + totalPriceDish2();
  document.getElementById('totalPrice').innerHTML = "Total $" + theTotalPrice;

}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <form action="" id="priceForm">
    <label class="dishes"><input type="checkbox" id="dish1" value="number1"> Dish Name 1</label><br>
    <label class="labelQuantPeople">Number of Dishes</label><br>
    <select id="quantityDish1" name='numberPeoplel1' onchange="calculateTotal()">
      <option class="quantDish1" value="0">0</option>
      <option class="quantDish1" value="1">1</option>
      <option class="quantDish1" value="2">2</option>
      <option class="quantDish1" value="3">3</option>
      <option class="quantDish1" value="4">4</option>
      <option class="quantDish1" value="5">5</option>
      <option class="quantDish1" value="6">6</option>
      <option class="quantDish1" value="7">7</option>
      <option class="quantDish1" value="8">8</option>
      <option class="quantDish1" value="9">9</option>
      <option class="quantDish1" value="10">10</option>
    </select><br>
    <label class="dishes"><input type="checkbox" id="dish2" value="number2"> Dish Name 2</label><br>
    <label class="labelQuantPeople">Number of Dishes</label><br>
    <select id="quantityDish2" name='numberPeoplel2' onchange="calculateTotal()">
      <option class="quantDish2" value="1">1</option>
      <option class="quantDish2" value="2">2</option>
      <option class="quantDish2" value="3">3</option>
      <option class="quantDish2" value="4">4</option>
      <option class="quantDish2" value="5">5</option>
      <option class="quantDish2" value="6">6</option>
      <option class="quantDish2" value="7">7</option>
      <option class="quantDish2" value="8">8</option>
      <option class="quantDish2" value="9">9</option>
      <option class="quantDish2" value="10">10</option>
    </select><br>
  </form>
</div>
<p id="totalPrice"></p>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Note on calculating prices with JavaScript (and for other languages in general), you might want to consider using a well established library because floating point arithmetics is not accurate. (tldr `theTotalPrice` will be wrong some of the time.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here comes my version. It works (if I got what you want correctly) but notice that it is not properly tested. There might be some issues related to the cross-browser compatibility too. And what Derek wrote in his comment is important as well. So, from the code below you can take first of all approaches and checkbox magic (I mean do not copypaste it - tweak it by yourself):

```js
 function getDishPrice(dish) {
     var quantity = dish.lastChild.lastChild.value ? dish.lastChild.lastChild.value : 0,
         price = dish.dataset.price ? dish.dataset.price : 0;
     return dish.firstChild.checked ? quantity * price : 0;
 }

function calculateTotal() {
    var dishes = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".dishes")),
        total = 0;
    dishes.filter(function(dish) {
        return dish.firstChild.checked;
    }).forEach(function(dish) {
        total += getDishPrice(dish);
    });    
    document.getElementById('totalPrice').textContent = "Total: $" + total;
}
var selects = document.getElementsByTagName("select"),
    inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
    i;
for (i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
    selects[i].addEventListener('change', calculateTotal, false);
    inputs[i].addEventListener('change', calculateTotal, false);
}
```

```css
#priceForm label {
  display: block;
}
#priceForm label div {
  display: none;
}
#priceForm label input[type="checkbox"]:checked + div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
    <form action="" id="priceForm" >
            <label class="dishes" data-price="10"><input type="checkbox" id="dish1"> Dish Name 1 <div>Number of Dishes
                <select id="quantityDish1">
                    <option class="quantDish1" value="0">0</option>
                    <option class="quantDish1" value="1">1</option>
                    <option class="quantDish1" value="2">2</option>
                    <option class="quantDish1" value="3">3</option>
                    <option class="quantDish1" value="4">4</option>
                    <option class="quantDish1" value="5">5</option>
                    <option class="quantDish1" value="6">6</option>
                    <option class="quantDish1" value="7">7</option>
                    <option class="quantDish1" value="8">8</option>
                    <option class="quantDish1" value="9">9</option>
                    <option class="quantDish1" value="10">10</option>
                </select></div></label>
                
            <label class="dishes" data-price="20"><input type="checkbox" id="dish2"> Dish Name 2 <div>Number of Dishes
                <select id="quantityDish2">
                    <option class="quantDish2" value="0">0</option>
                    <option class="quantDish2" value="1">1</option>
                    <option class="quantDish2" value="2">2</option>
                    <option class="quantDish2" value="3">3</option>
                    <option class="quantDish2" value="4">4</option>
                    <option class="quantDish2" value="5">5</option>
                    <option class="quantDish2" value="6">6</option>
                    <option class="quantDish2" value="7">7</option>
                    <option class="quantDish2" value="8">8</option>
                    <option class="quantDish2" value="9">9</option>
                    <option class="quantDish2" value="10">10</option>
                    </select></div></label>
    </form>
</div>
<p id="totalPrice">Total: $0</p>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! I will take a deeper look into it to better understand what you did. There are some commands that I'm still not aware off and will me a lot to learn.